# how to store Usability related values (Font, Dimension, Color,...) in properties file using ResoucesBundles

Tags: java, swing, properties, resourcebundle, externalizing

I'm able to fetch the Strings using a properties file and ResourceBundle class using `ResourceBundle.getString()`. And even able to fetch int and float objects also using:

```
int a = (int) ResourceBundle.getObject("IntKey");
float b = (float) ResourceBundle.getObject("FloatKey");
```

But I want to know to how to fetch some complex objects like fonts?

```
Font font = (Font) ResourceBundle.getObject("FontKey");
```

But how to store the Font values in properties file? can I store the object like: `new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12);` into a key:value of a properties file.

## Update 1:

@doublesharp your answer is fine. Actually I'm not extending ResourceBundle class to override handleGetObjects() method. My implemention is as shown below:

```
public class Usability {

    private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "com.upgrade.utility.resources.Usability";

    private static final ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);

    private Usability() {}

    public static String get(String key, Object ... args) {

        String value = null;
        try {
            value = RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key);
            
            for (Object var : args) {
                if (var != null) {
                    try {
                        value = value.replaceFirst("@", var.toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
            }
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            value = '!' + key + '!';
        }
        return value;
    }
    
    public static Font getFont(String key){
        Font value = null;
        try {
            String fontName = (String) RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".Name");
            Integer fontStyle = Integer.parseInt(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".Style"));
            Integer fontSize = Integer.parseInt(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".Size"));
            value = new Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            value = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
        }catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            value = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
        }
        
        System.out.println("Font"+ value);
        return value;
        
    }
}
```

How Can I use your method in this case? I'm new to JAVA, can you please tell me how to modify my implementation to use the method handleGetObjects() ?

## Update 2:

@doublesharp: From your last comment, I've modified like this, But getting Class Cast exception in 3rd line of Usability class.

```
public class Usability {

    private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "com.upgrade.utility.resources.Usability";

    public static final MyResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = (MyResourceBundle) MyResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);

    private Usability() {}

    public static String get(String key, Object ... args) {

        String value = null;
        try {
            value = RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key);
            
            for (Object var : args) {
                if (var != null) {
                    try {
                        value = value.replaceFirst("@", var.toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
            }
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            value = '!' + key + '!';
        }
        return value;
    }
    
}
```

My extended ResourceBunlde class is:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MyResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle{

    @Override
    public Object handleGetObject(String key) {
       if (key.contains("Font")) {
           return getFont(key);
       } else if (key.contains("color")){
           return getColor(key);
       }else if (key.contains("Dimension")){
           return getDimension(key);
       }
    return this.getObject(key);
    }
    
     public Font getFont(String key){
            Font value = null;
            try {
                String fontName = (String) this.getString(key+ ".Name");
                Integer fontStyle = Integer.parseInt(this.getString(key+ ".Style"));
                Integer fontSize = Integer.parseInt(this.getString(key+ ".Size"));
                value = new Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize);
            } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
                value = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
            }catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                value = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
            }
            return value;
        }
     
     public Color getColor(String key){
            Color value = null;
            try {
                Integer R = Integer.parseInt(this.getString(key+ ".R"));
                Integer G = Integer.parseInt(this.getString(key+ ".G"));
                Integer B = Integer.parseInt(this.getString(key+ ".B"));
                value = new Color(R, G, B);
            } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
//              value = new Color("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
            }catch (NullPointerException npe) {
//              value = new Color("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
            }
            return value;
        }
     
     public Dimension getDimension(String key){
            Dimension value = null;
            try {
                Integer X = Integer.parseInt(this.getString(key+ ".X"));
                Integer Y = Integer.parseInt(this.getString(key+ ".Y"));
                value = new Dimension(X, Y);
            } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
//              value = new Color("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
            }catch (NullPointerException npe) {
//              value = new Color("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
            }
            return value;
        }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

How to resolve this exception?

**And also Is there problem in my answer?** using which I was just calling like

```
Usability.getFont("JPanelUpgradeTypeScreen.ElementLabelFont");
```

But using your answer techinque, I need to call it like (Type conversion is needed in call) :

```
(Font)Usability.RESOURCE_BUNDLE.handleGetObject("JPanelUpgradeTypeScreen.ElementLabelFont");
```

Comment: I would store: font family, variant and size.

Comment: Properties files are not a binary format, thus they are not suited for storing serialized objects...how ever, you could store the properties of the objects (as RC is suggesting) instead.  This would mean you would need a way to parse this value, such as a utility method.  We do something similar for storing things like colors (in RGB format)

Comment: @merlachandra Is your target to get `Font` by searching key? Try to use `xml` configuration.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thats what the `ResourceBundle.handleGetObject()` method is for - when you call `getObject(key)` it will use that method to try and construct your Object, potentially using other properties.

Comment: @doublesharp: so using handleGetObject(), we can capture the type of key (here font) then construct and return the respective value object (here Font)...Similiarly using one more if inside this method, we can make use with other type of object (like Dimension)...Am I Right?

Comment: @merlachandra if I understand you correctly, then yes. Please see my answer below for an example.

Comment: @doublesharp Please see my update-1 in the question.

Comment: `You need to replace `ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE` with a new class that you create. It could be something like 'MyResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle {}` which then has your implementation of `handleGetObject()` as in my answer below. The code above would be updated to reference `private static final MyResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = MyResourceBundle.getBundle();`. The `getFont()` method would be removed and the code more or less moved to `MyResourceBundle.handleGetObject()`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a class I've defined the following functions, which I call whenever I need to access the usability related valus. All the usability related values are stored at a common place (properties file).

```
private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "com.testApp.resources.properties.Usability";

private static final ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);

    public static Font getFont(String key){
        Font value = null;
        try {
            String fontName = (String) RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".Name");
            Integer fontStyle = Integer.parseInt(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".Style"));
            Integer fontSize = Integer.parseInt(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".Size"));
            value = new Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            value = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
        }catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            value = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static Color getColor(String key){
        Color value = null;
        try {
            Integer R = Integer.parseInt(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".R"));
            Integer G = Integer.parseInt(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".G"));
            Integer B = Integer.parseInt(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".B"));
            value = new Color(R, G, B);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
//            value = new Color("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
        }catch (NullPointerException npe) {
//          value = new Color("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
        }
        return value;
    }

 public static Dimension getDimension(String key){
        Dimension value = null;
        try {
            Integer X = Integer.parseInt(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".X"));
            Integer Y = Integer.parseInt(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".Y"));
            value = new Dimension(X, Y);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
//            value = new Color("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
        }catch (NullPointerException npe) {
//          value = new Color("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

In properties file which I'm maintaining for usability related values the properties are defined as below:

```
#BLACK
ElementLabelFont.Color.R=4
ElementLabelFont.Color.G=4
ElementLabelFont.Color.B=4

#ScreenPanel dimension
ScreenPanel.Dimension.X=632
ScreenPanel.Dimension.Y=625

#Font of jCheckBoxYesAgreement
JPanelPreUpgradeStepsScreen.jCheckBoxYesAgreement.Font.Name=Tahoma
JPanelPreUpgradeStepsScreen.jCheckBoxYesAgreement.Font.Style=0
JPanelPreUpgradeStepsScreen.jCheckBoxYesAgreement.Font.Size=12
```

Answer (score 2):

Objects should not be initialized in a properties file.You should use only constant values inside a properties file

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `handleGetObject()` method for your implementation. You can't store the object definition in the properties file, but you can store it's initialization parameters as keys, and use those when returning your object. In this example you would set properties for `font-family` (Tahoma, etc), `font-type` (text value used to map to Font.BOLD, etc), and `font-size`. Calling `MyResourceBundle.getObject("font")` (a class that extends `ResourceBundle`) would call your implementation of `handleGetObject()` and then use the previous values to create your object:

```
@Override
public Object handleGetObject(String key) {
   if (key.equals("font")) {
      String family = this.getString("font-family");
      String strType = this.getString("font-type");
      int type;
      switch (strType){
          case "bold": Font.BOLD;
          default: type = Font.PLAIN;
      }
      int size = this.getInt("font-size");
      return new Font(family, type, size);
   } else {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your custom object and then wrap binary code with base64 encoding, for example, which you can write to properties as a string

Answer (score 0):

Taking the inputs from all your answers and Comments: This is answer, which is satisfying my requirement:

```
public static Font getFont(String key){
        Font value = null;
        try {
            String fontName = (String) RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".Name");
            Integer fontStyle = Integer.parseInt(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".Style"));
            Integer fontSize = Integer.parseInt(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key+ ".Size"));
            value = new Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            value = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
        }catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            value = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);
        }
        return value;   
    }
```

inside properties file I've stored as

```
#Usability
    DialogTextFont.Name=Tahoma
    DialogTextFont.Style=0
    DialogTextFont.Size=12
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote answers you found helpful, and maybe say why.