# Get filepath of font in Java 7

Tags: swing, reflection, fonts, java-7, filepath

Is there a way to get the file path of a font in Java 7?

Note: I got all the system font names through:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
String []fontFamilies = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
```

Would I possibly use reflection? Any help would be great.

Comment: *"Is there a way to get the file path of a font in Java 7?"*  ..Why?

Comment: Can this post help you as an alternative ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947661/how-to-store-usability-related-values-font-dimension-color-in-properties

Comment: I need font locations as they need to be specified by an avconv process that my app is using.